# Send two Arrays of Strings and Ints as matchData

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am working on a turn based game with Game Center. I want to send an Array of Strings and an Array of Ints as matchData. I know how to create both, but I only know how to send one of them...

This is how i create the String Array:

```
var strings = [String]()  
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(strings)
```

This is how i create the Int Array:

```
var array : [Int] = []  
let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count * sizeof(Int))
```

This is how I send the data i create

```
currentMatch?.endTurnWithNextParticipants([nextParticipant], turnTimeout: 20, matchData: data, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)

                } else {
                    //Data sent

                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to wrap both in a dictionary and then serialize the dictionary:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject([
    "strings":strings,
    "numbers":array
])
```

Then to recover the original data, you can use:

```
guard let recovered = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? [String:AnyObject],
    let strings = recovered["strings"] as? [String],
    let array = recovered["numbers"] as? [Int] else {
        // recovery failed... deal with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your matchData using `GKTurnBasedMatch.loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:` and then use that match data if it exists in the completion block.

Comment: I know how to retrieve the data and convert it back to its original type. But i dont know how to send both arrays...